# Kafka Connect for Elastic search fails to publish few messages out of 10million messages to Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We have a Kafka connect set up for sinking the events from Kafka to Elastic. We are experiencing data consistency issue and was hoping to get some guidance here.

We are using the open source kafka connect confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:6.1.0
Its working really great for us for our regular use but with load test we found issues.
We applied load that resulted in 10million unique events on the Kafka topic. When we checked the elastic search and we found 96 documents were missing, they never made it to elastic.

We checked the kafka connect logs and the kubernetes pod where we are running the kafka connect and found below:

1. The CPU on the pod was very high and in turn it caused the pods to get killed multiple times throughout the lifecycle of the load test. Not sure if this could be an issue for this missing document. We have addressed this issue now by adding more CPU and auto scaling.
2. In the logs we saw Gateway timeout error (504) returned from the elastic service itself too and which it seems in turn resulted in Bulk request to fail with error like this:

```
    ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=kafka-connect-gds-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: Bulk request failed. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
```

3. There were no other errors, there were no messages in the DLQ topic either.
4. We manually checked and compared the events that made it to elastic with the one that didn't and didn't find any difference, so we believe this Gateway timeout error must have caused the issue with 96 files to not show up in elastic. But we could be wrong.

Also this issue should have been resolved after the gateway error went away and pods were restarted. The counts are still off. So it seems like the SinkTask failed to write to elastic but the committed the offset for consumer group? That is why after the restart the Kafka connect is not picking up those events that never made it to Elastic.
I would expect these 2 things to get done in a transaction. I was trying to read through the implementation here https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/WorkerSinkTask.java but couldn't really figure out the right flow.

So I was hoping to get some insights here on what we could be doing wrong.

Here are our Kafka connect settings:

```
{
    "name": "${KC_ES_CONNECTOR_NAME}",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "connection.url": "${KC_ES_DOMAIN_ENDPOINT}",
    "type.name": "kafkaconnect",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "schema.ignore": "true",
    "topics": "${KC_ES_TOPICS}",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "DELETE",
    "behavior.on.malformed.documents": "IGNORE",
    "batch.size": "500",
    "read.timeout.ms": "60000",
    "linger.ms": "100",
    "write.method": "upsert",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "${KC_ES_NAMESPACE}.kc.gds.dlq",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "errors.retry.timeout": "-1",
    "errors.retry.delay.max.ms": "60000",
    "predicates": "isNullRecord",
    "predicates.isNullRecord.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.RecordIsTombstone",
    "transforms": "dropNullRecords,transformserecords",
    "transforms.dropNullRecords.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Filter",
    "transforms.dropNullRecords.predicate": "isNullRecord",
    "transforms.transformserecords.type": "com.mycompany.kafka.connect.smt.TransformSERecord\$Value",
    "transforms.transformserecords.transform": "true"
}
```

We do have a custom SMT too, which does very basic transformations like adding few new fields and ignore certain events and route record to the right elastic index by conventions. All the 10M files were identical so the transformation worked the same way for all of them and we can confirm that with the logging we have in for SMT.

When this issue occurred, the Kafka connect was working with 1 worker with 1 pod (process). Definitely under provisioned for the type of test but we have addressed this since. We are planning to repeat the test but was hoping for guidance on anything obvious we are missing here.

Regards,
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

> Kafka connect is not picking up those events that never made it to Elastic. I would expect these 2 things to get done in a transaction.

There is live and ongoing discussion in the kafka internal contributer community about supporting more exactly once behavior on sink / source connectors , it is hard to achieve this behavior because there is no shared transcation between two systems, most connectors supports at least once or doing upsert to create idempotent actions.

Specifically about the elastic search sink connector from Confluent

Exactly once delivery
The connector relies on Elasticsearch’s idempotent write semantics to ensure exactly once delivery to Elasticsearch. By setting IDs in Elasticsearch documents, the connector can ensure exactly once delivery. If keys are included in Kafka messages, then they are translated to Elasticsearch document IDs automatically. When the keys are not included, or are explicitly ignored, the connector will use topic+partition+offset as the key, ensuring each message in Kafka has exactly one document corresponding to it in Elasticsearch.

Dead Letter Queue
This connector supports the Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) functionality. For information about accessing and using the DLQ, see Confluent Platform Dead Letter Queue.

Comment: Thanks Ran for your inputs. So essentially what you are describing on the gap that its impossible to guarantee that all the Kafka events can be written to elastic. If elastic for some reason is not available, the events will be dropped like what we saw in our test. We do have unique ids in our event and not having issue with deliveries if ES is up all the time.